# Custom field is Percent(3, 6) and email template displays it to 13 decimal places

Tags: visualforce, email-template

How is this possible?

I would assume a VisualForce email template would by default display it to the number of decimal places it is defined as?

How in this instance can it display a value that is stored to 6 decimal places, to 13 decimal places?

[image]

Email Template code:

```
    <p style="padding: 10px 30px 10px 30px; margin: 10px;">
        Utilization:
        <b>{!relatedTo.Blah__UtilisationPercentage__c}</b><br />
    </p>
```

Comment: Can you share some of your Visualforce code and maybe a screenshot of your field definition please?

Comment: I've tried to do this. The image has come out unreadably small, but it's fine if you open it in a new tab. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, I think I've spotted your problem, give it a go. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce numeric values are actually stored as generic decimal types internally, i suspect by making a raw/direct binding to the field your simply exposing this value unformatted. The recommended approach for outputting field values is to use [apex:outputField](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_outputField.htm), this will handle the correct formatting and localisation of the value (commas, thousand separators). Try this...

```
<apex:outputField value="{!relatedTo.Blah__UtilisationPercentage__c}"/>
```

> A read-only display of a label and value for a field on a Salesforce object. An apex:outputField component respects the attributes of the associated field, including how it should be displayed to the user

Comment: Thanks. Tried this. Works! The HTML part of my template now displays to 6 DP. Interestingly, I notice that the plain text part of the template, which is still using the old method e.g. Utilization:        {!relatedTo.Blah__UtilisationPercentage__c displays 100% as 100.0%. So there seems to be inconsistent behaviour here.

Comment: @finisterre please upvote and mark as answered if that helps you ,so that its beneficial for other users .